# Linking filenames or labels to numeric index

Tags: c

In a C99+SDL game, I have an array that contains sound effects (SDL_mixer chunk data and some extra flags and filename string) and is referenced by index such as "sounds[2].data".

I'd like to be able to call sounds by filename, but I don't want to strcmp all the array until a match is found. This way as I add more sounds, or change the order, or allow for player-defined sound mods, they can still be called with a common identifier (such as "SHOT01" or "EXPL04").

What would be the fastest approach for this? I heard about hashing, which would result in something similar to lua's string indexes (such as table["field"]) but I don't know anything about the topic, and seems fairly complicated.

Just in case it matters, I plan to have filenames or labels be from 6 to 8 all caps filenames (such as "SHOT01.wav").

So to summarize, where can I learn about hashing short strings like that, or what would be the fastest way to keep track of something like sound effects so they can be called using arbitrary labels or identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you can probably just keep all the sounds in a sorted data structure and use a fast search algorithm to find matches.  Something like a binary search is very simple implement and it gives good performance.

However, if you are interested in hash tables and hashing, the basics of it all are pretty simple.  There is no place like Wikipedia to get the basics down and you can then tailor your searches better on Google to find more in depth articles.

The basics are you start out with a fixed size array and store everything in there. To figure out where to store something you take the key (in your case the sound name) and you perform some operation on it such that it gives you an exact location where the value can be found.  So the simplest case for string hashing is just adding up all the letters in the string as integer values then take the value and use modulus to give you an index in your array.

position = SUM(string letters) % [array size]

Of course naturally multiple strings will have same sum and thus give you the same position.  This is called a collision, and collisions can be handled in many ways.  The simplest way is to have an array of lists rather than array of values, and simply append to the list every there there is a collision.  When searching for a value, simply iterate the lists and find the value you need.

Ideally a good hashing algorithm will have few collisions and quick hashing algorithm thus providing huge performance boost.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I think I get the idea. I need to have an array the size (in members) of the desired hash format (array[65535] for 16-bit for example) and then use the hash functions to get the indexes for every label, right? What would be a good algorithm to look into when my strings are limited to few, ascii-only (and all caps) values? Would I be able to use 16 bit hashes with that character set? Space is a bit of a concern, on the long run.

Comment: Ideally you'd probably want to have storage container (array) that's only as big as the expected number of elements to be stored. If you only plan on having a dozen sounds then a size of 8 to 16 would suffice.  As for the hashing function... when you add up all the ASCII character as integers you'll end up with some number much larger than 8 or 16, thus you use the modulus.  `index = sum % 16;` will result in index being the remainder of the division of `sum` by `16`, thus always resulting in a number less than `16`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. I successfully wrote one with a Bernstein hashing and linked list "buckets". Seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, when it comes to mapping objects with a set of string keys, hash tables are often the way to go.
I think this article on wikipedia is a good starting point to understand hash table mechanism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table